# How to create an Oracle stored procedure to lock user accounts not logged onto database for more than 90 days

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

How do I create an Oracle Stored Procedure to lock user accounts that's not logged onto the database for more than 90 days?

I assumed that I could create a Profile Object and list the Resource Parameters in my database but I am using Oracle 11g and it appears that feature doesn't exist.

This is what I tried so far:

```
select username from dba_audit_trail
where  action_name = 'LOGON'
group  by username
having max(timestamp) < sysdate - 90
```

I also attempted to create a profile attempting to use INACTIVE_ACCOUNT_TIME as my Resource Parameters but it does not exist in Oracle 11g:

```
CREATE PROFILE time_limit LIMIT 
INACTIVE_ACCOUNT_TIME 90;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your attempts, explaining the issues you are having.

Comment: select username from dba_audit_trail
where  action_name = 'LOGON'
group  by username
having max(timestamp) < sysdate - 90

Comment: alter user username account lock;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 12c it can be:

```
begin
for x in 
(select username
  from dba_users
  where last_login < sysdate - 90) 
loop
  execute immediate 'alter user ' || x.username || ' account lock';
end loop;
end;
```

If you're using 11g you may try your query for loop:

```
begin
for x in 
(select username from dba_audit_trail
 where  action_name = 'LOGON'
 group  by username
 having max(timestamp) < sysdate - 90) 
loop
  execute immediate 'alter user ' || x.username || ' account lock';
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Your answer is great, but I just have a question regarding your select statement. The where clause has "last_login". Where are you getting that from?

Comment: `dba_users` table has such column.

Comment: No..`DBA_USERS` doesnot has such `column`.. Check.. you can modify your block and get it as a passed paramater

Comment: An error was encountered performing the requested operation:         ORA-00904: "LAST_LOGIN": invalid identifier

Comment: In 12c it has. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-309FCCB2-2E8D-4371-9FC5-7F3B10E2A8C0.htm#REFRN23302

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11g. The reference link is Oracle 12c Release 1 (12.1)

Comment: Sorry that's my fault I haven't noticed that you use 11g. I'll rectify my answer