# Select User Accounts Not Logged In Database for 180 Days to Revoke Roles

Tags: select, oracle11g, user-roles

How do I write a SELECT statement that "show all user accounts" that have not logged into the database for more than 180 days? My goal is to revoke the users accounts roles that have not logged into the database for more the 180 days.

In other words, I need to find the roles that are currently granted to current users who have not logged in for more than 180 days.

I am using Oracle 11g.

Thank you.

Comment: You already posted a [question to find users that have not logged on in the last 90 days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829385/how-to-create-an-oracle-stored-procedure-to-lock-user-accounts-not-logged-onto-d), so you already know this part. Please edit the question posting what you already have and clarifying the part you need help for. I guess you only need a way to find roles associated to a set of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Oracle 12.1 and above you could use:

```
select role
from   dba_roles
where  role not in ( select granted_role
                     from   dba_role_privs
                     where  grantee in ( select username
                                         from   dba_users
                                         where  username not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM')
                                           and  last_login >= trunc(sysdate)-180
                                       )
                   )
;
```

In Oracle 11 the innermost subquery will not work, because the column `last_login` did not exist in the `dba_users` table. Replace the innermost subquery with

```
select username 
from   dba_audit_trail
where  action_name = 'LOGON'
  and  username not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM')
  and  timestamp >= trunc(sysdate) - 180
```

I tested the 12c version and it produces the correct output on my machine; I didn't test the 11g version, since I don't have an 11g database to test on.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm teaching myself Oracle so I apologize for not connecting the dots.

Answer (score 0):

The filter needs to be `last_login <= sysdate-180;` in above queries

Comment: Can you give more details and explain why?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).